# How do I sum all elements in a ublas matrix?

Tags: c++, boost

According to [this page](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/overview.htm) there should be a `sum` function provided in `ublas`, but I can't get the following to compile:

```
boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<double> mymatrix;
std::cout << boost::numeric::ublas::sum(mymatrix);
```

error is:

> testcpp:146:144: error: no matching function for call to
>   ‘sum(boost::numeric::ublas::matrix&)’

I'm `#include`ing:

```
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/matrix.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/matrix_proxy.hpp>
```

Am I missing an include, or did I misunderstand the docs? How would I achieve this (I'm trying to sum up all elements of a matrix and produce a single `double`)?

Comment: That unary sum is a vector-, not a matrix-expression. The trivial isomorphism M_m,n ≅ R**{m*n} appears to be left out an ansatz. No more sure about visibility, but I think you can get to underlying (flat) container. Then you can use e.g. std::partial_sum on that.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in comments, `sum` only applies to vectors ([see documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/vector_expression.htm#vector_reductions))

You could certainly get at `m.data()` and sum the values that way, but you are using a linear algebra library! Multiply a row vector of 1's by your matrix, and sum the result:

```
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/matrix.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/io.hpp>

namespace bls = boost::numeric::ublas;
int main()
{
    bls::matrix<double> m(3, 3);
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < m.size1(); ++i)
        for (unsigned j = 0; j < m.size2(); ++j)
            m(i, j) = 3 * i + j;

   std::cout << "Sum of all elements of " << m << " is "
             << sum(prod(bls::scalar_vector<double>(m.size1()), m)) << '\n';
}
```

A more reusable approach would be to define a `sum` that takes a `matrix_expression`, as the [shark library](http://image.diku.dk/shark/doxygen_pages/html/matrix__expression_8hpp_source.html) did.